# Error while crawling using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrap some pages, however whenever I am trying to start the crawler, it stops with following error.

```
from OpenSSL._util import lib as pyOpenSSLlib
ImportError: No module named _util
```

I have installed pyopenssl v13.1. Also the `brew link openssl` is executed. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Operating System - Mac OS High Sierra
Python - V2.7
PIP - 10.1

Comment: were you able to find anything, facing the exact same issue

Comment: switched to casperjs :)

Answer (score 1):

this is the version problem use the code update it
`pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed pyopenssl`